# AJAX call in ASP.NET MVC application not calling Action method

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following ASP.NET MVC .cshtml file in which I do the following:
Grab the Name & Id values from `MyObject` and create a `DropDownList` out of them, when the user selects an item in the Drop Down box I attempt to use AJAX to call `TheMethodToCall` which is a method in `TheController`, and attempt to display the text result returned by `TheMethodTocall`.

```
@model List<MyWebApp.Models.MyObject>

@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            @Html.DropDownList("SelectFromDropdownList", Model.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id
                }), "This is the default DropDownList option", new { @class="custom-select", @id="mydropdownid"})
            <script>
                $(function(){
                    $('#SelectFromDropdownList').change(function () {
                        var typeFeed = $(this).val();
                        // Perform AJAX call
                        $.get("@Url.Action("TheMethodToCall", "TheController")", { TypeFeed: typeFeed }, function (result){
                            @Html.DisplayText(result);
                            });
                        });
                    });
            </script>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I'm having a couple of issues, please help! Here they are:

1. I have put my Visual Studio debugger breakpoint in the `TheMethodToCall` method, but it does not get hit when the user selects an item from the `DropDownList`.
2. Is this the correct way of displaying the `result` text which is returned form `TheMethodToCall`?

---

**Update**

I appreciate the answers so far, but I'm setting a breakpoint in this method, but it is still not being called. I did change `$('#SelectFromDropdownList').change(function ()` to `$('#mydropdownid').change(function ()`. Is there anything else to do?

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string TheMethodToCall()
    {
        return "This is a test";
    }
```

Comment: You have added `new { id="mydropdownid" }` which generates `<select id="mydropdownid"` ... >` so you do not have an element with `id="SelectFromDropdownList"` - therefore the script needs to be `$('#mydropdownid').change(function () {`

Comment: And no - `@Html.DisplayText(result);` will not work. To add the result to the DOM you need `$(someElement).html(result)`

Comment: Why do you have `[WebMethod()]`? And it should be `public  ActionResult TheMethodToCall() { return Content("This is a test"); }`

Comment: Also, you're trying to pass data to the function `{ TypeFeed: typeFeed }` but your function doesn't accept any parameters. For now while you're learning, don't send any data. It just complicates things.

Comment: I feel like I'm crazy for saying this, but it is still not working! I have incorporated all of your suggestions, but still `TheMethodToCall` does not get called (breakpoint not hit inside of it). Could it be that i'm missing the AJAX library? Or that `@Url.Action` is the wrong method to be using? For the 2nd parameter in `Url.Action`, if I had a controller named `HouseController`, would I put `House` or `HouseController` as this method's 2nd parameter?

Comment: @Emilia Your use `House`, not `HouseController`. What errors are you getting in the browser console? Do you even have `jquery-{version},js` loaded in the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Cool, thanks for pointing me to Chrome Developer tools. That really gave me the tools to debug this much farther than before. The first issue was that $ was undefined (I needed to add the script import statement). The second was that I had to remove the `static` identifier from `TheMethodToCall`. So now the method gets called, but returned value isn't displayed.

Comment: Read the 2nd comment :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well actually, now the code looks like this for the text label item above the JavaScript `<script>` tags: `@Html.Label("", "", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", @id="dataSavedStatus" })` and this is the last line of the $.get function (I changed it to a $.post): `function (result) { $('#dataSavedStatus').html(result); });` This still doesn't seem to update `dataSavedStatus` with "This is a test".

Comment: It will (assuming you have made all the changes in the controller I noted in my previous comments). But why in the world are you using `@Html.LabelFor()` to create a `<label>` which is clearly not associated with an form control. Just use `<span id="dataSavedStatus"></span>`

Comment: @Emilia just some general advice - try simplifying your code while troubleshooting so you can more easily pinpoint the failure point. For example, at the moment your `function (result)` is trying to target another element and change it's contents. You don't know if the server is failing to provide a response or if the JavaScript in your function is failing. Replace the function content (temporarily) with something much more basic like `alert(result);` or `console.log(result)`. Once you've confirmed the server is responding correctly, then try and insert that response into a HTML element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your .change listener is using the wrong ID. The dropdown list has ID of `mydropdownid` but in your jQuery you have `$('#SelectFromDropdownList').change`. Change it to `$('#mydropdownid').change`
2. The way you're using the result in the AJAX response isn't correct. You're trying to use server-side Razor/C# (which executes when the page initially loads) to handle a response that occurs long after the page has loaded. You need to use JavaScript only in the response function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm very new to JS/AJAX, so can you please edit the code to use JavaScript only in the response function?

Comment: It depend what you want to do with the response. One example could be to just show a popup/alert with whatever the response says:
`function (result){
                            alert(result);
                            });`